# define date serialization in spring boot on dto-level

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

Is there a way define the serialisation of dates in the DTO?
The new default configuration from spring boot to serialise dates is now 
`spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false`. I can change that, but it has a global effect on the serialisation.

My problem is that i have to support multiple api-versions.
for example
v1 needs the date to be serialized to a timestamp and v2 on the other hand as string.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jackson/FasterXml, you can use `@JsonFormat`. The annotation can be on both *type* level as well as *per-field* level.

**Sample usage:**

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date date;
```

**Reference JavaDoc**: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html

Comment: Thats a good solution if you have one or just a few dates. But is annoying when you have tons of dates where you have to add this.

Comment: You missed this line - The annotation can be on both type level as well as per-field level.? You can annotate on the class level. Gv a try ? I shared Javadoc that gives more info that I can type.